Unity Input System doesn't detect other control schemes
I'm working on a quick top-down character controller, and I want to detect whether my current control scheme being used is either the gamepad or the keyboard. My issue is that Unity seems to default and only ever detect gamepad, even when I've unplugged/detached any gamepad controller and strictly using a keyboard and mouse.
The main way im trying to detect this for my main movement script is by having a function called on the 'Controls Changed Event' in the Player Input Component
It only ever fires as true, and in practice it only runs once on startup and never again.
public void OnDeviceChanged(PlayerInput playInput)
    {
        isGamepadActive = playInput.currentControlScheme.Equals("GamePad") ? true : false;

        Debug.Log(isGamepadActive);
    }

I'm having a hard time seeing if anyone else has a similar issue, and I'm suspecting it might be how unity is detecting/using the current control scheme.
I hope someone has a fix, and I appreciate your time!

Potential Issue A: Multiple PlayerInput's
If you have more than one PlayerInput component in your scene, then it will bind to a single input device. You'll either need to remove all but one PlayerInput component from your scene, or create your own component that doesn't rely on PlayerInput.
Potential Issue B: Setup issue
Check whether you have selected the default control scheme from your InputActionsAsset to be Gamepad on the PlayerInput inspector. Are you usng a single InputActionsAsset with multiple ControlSchemes, or multiple InputActionsAsset's each with their own control schemes?
If that's no help...
You can do a search through a list of InputActionAssets to get the currently active control scheme, without relying on the PlayerInput component's event:
    [SerializeField]
    private List<InputActionAsset> inputActionAssets;

    private bool TryFindControlScheme(InputDevice inputDevice, out InputControlScheme? controlScheme)
    {
        // try to get the control scheme directly from the device
        foreach (InputActionAsset inputActionAsset in inputActionAssets)
        {
            controlScheme = InputControlScheme.FindControlSchemeForDevice(inputDevice, inputActionAsset.controlSchemes);
            if (controlScheme.HasValue) { return true; }
        }
        
        // try to get the control scheme from inputActionAsset's controlSchemes' supported devices
        foreach (var inputActionAsset in inputActionAssets)
        {
            foreach (var inputControlScheme in inputActionAsset.controlSchemes)
            {
                if (inputControlScheme.SupportsDevice(inputDevice))
                {
                    controlScheme = inputControlScheme;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }

        // unable to find control scheme
        controlScheme = null;
        return false;
    }

